# Шаблон поиска в Python

Tags: python, поиск, текст, шаблоны

Не могу понять как составить шаблон в Python

Есть ячейка:

```
Спать легли однажды ДЕТИ – Окна все затемнены. А проснулись НА РАССВЕТЕ – В окнах свет – и НЕТ ВОЙНЫ!
```

Необходимо найти все слова и фразы (!) написанные заглавными буквами:

```
ДЕТИ
А
НА РАССВЕТЕ
В
НЕТ ВОЙНЫ
```

Используя шаблон (\b([А-ЯЁA-Z]+)\b)

```
Получаем итог: 
ДЕТИ
А
НА
РАССВЕТЕ
В
НЕТ
ВОЙНЫ
```

разбивает фразы по словам

Используя шаблон (\b([А-ЯЁA-Z]+)\b \b([А-ЯЁA-Z]+)\b)

```
Получаем итог:
НА РАССВЕТЕ
НЕТ ВОЙНЫ
```

не ищет одиночные слова

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конкретно в Вашем примере подойдёт

```
\b([А-ЯЁA-Z]+)\b.(\b[А-ЯЁA-Z]+\b)*
```

но этот шаблон просто предполагает возможное наличие второго слова. В примере желаемые словосочетания имеют семантический смысл. А фактически шаблон будет находить любые рядом стоящие слова, написанные с заглавной буквы.

Поэтому не очень уверен что именно это вы хотели, но регулярные выражения ничего про семантику не знают.

Comment: Да, спасибо! Это то что надо! все работает.

Comment: А можете пояснить синтаксис? что значит точка и *

Comment: Точка в синтаксисе регулярных выражений означает "Здесь может быть любой символ" (у вас там может быть пробел, он тоже символ). Звёздочка означает "0 или более раз". Т.е в нашем случае вторая группа может быть а может и не быть. Благодаря звёздочке подходящими вхождениями считаются как с одним словом так и с двумя.